# How to display 4 products in a row on PLP

Tags: magento2.3.3

I have a situation where I need to display 4 products in a row on the product listing page whereas by default it's 5 in a row.

I know how to achieve this by overriding simple CSS but there is a condition I do not have the authority to override the existing CSS and so I don't really option as per the CSS is concerned so is there a way I can achieve through `.phtml` file by some minor customization.

Comment: please also provide some suggestion instead of making lots of edit to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom theme is inheriting from Blank or Luma, by default on desktop view there are 4 products in a row.
So if you're viewing 5 in a row, it means that the default css of PLP was already changed.
You are binded in not using css rules, and that might be more than a concern. Grid system of PLP is totally controlled by css. Example:

```
.product-item {
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc((100% - 6%)/4);
}
```

Yes, you can include a new grid system, like bootstrap for example, and call it's classes in the phtml but at the same time you should remove the original classes as well making sure that only the new grid rules will be loaded. I hope this hint helps you dealing with this problem.

Comment: no i have not done any changes in css yet and my parent theme is luma

Comment: the default PLP of Luma looks like this: http://magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/index.php/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html